# Keycloak X.509 authentication using proxy

Tags: authentication, keycloak, x509, client-certificates

I am trying to configure X.509 client authentication on the Keycloak 17.0.0 (Quarkus). I am using the `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0` to deploy it in my Kubernetes environment.

I am running the Keycloak according the https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/docs/guides/src/main/server/reverseproxy.adoc:

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build --spi-x509cert-lookup-provider=nginx
/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev --spi-x509cert-lookup-nginx-ssl-client-cert=SSL_CLIENT_CERT
```

And I have the configuration of the X.509 client certificate authentication in the Browser and Direct Grant authentication flows, enabled in the authentication bindings, according the https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_x509.

So expecting that the Keycloak will take the client certificate from SSL_CLIENT_CERT header and authenticate based on that.

However, trying to use the certificate to authenticate, I receive:

```
{
    "error_description": "X509 client certificate is missing.",
    "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

This is my `curl`:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/TEST/protocol/openid-connect/token \
       -H "SSL_CLIENT_CERT: <cert_content>" \
       -d "grant_type=password&username=&password=&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET"
```

There is a little documentation about how to do it behind the proxy in the Keycloak Quarkus version.

Anyone able to make it work?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

1.) You need to use TLS, so you can't use `http` protocol for that - `https` is required. Ideal TLS config will have proper cert setup, otherwise curl will need `--insecure`.

2.) `-H "SSL_CLIENT_CERT: <cert_content>" \` adds HTTP header, so that's is level 7 (OSI model), but TLS connection is level 4. So this is wrong.

Curl has another parameters `--cert`, `--key` for mutual (X.509) TLS. You should to have also proper data encoding, so in theory correct curl:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  --cert /<path>/client-pem.crt \
  --key /<path>/client-pem.key \
  --data-urlencode "client_id=CLIENT_ID" \
  --data-urlencode "client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
  --data-urlencode "username=" \
  --data-urlencode "password=" \
  https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/TEST/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Comment: I am running the Keycloak behind the proxy, with the `KC_PROXY=edge`, therefore I am trying to simulate the certificate forwarded in the header and using the `http` instead of `https`. Running behind the proxy, that will terminate TLS before the Keycloak is the desired setup.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The keycloak application should read the certificate from a header. The MTLS is offloaded to the proxy. Keycloak uses providers to get the client certificate from a header. See here for the sourcecode of these providers:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/x509